# How to delete all contents of JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that contains text for my project. For my project, I want to give the user the option to restart it completely. This requires it to delete the contents of the JSON file. How would I do that using python?

Comment: Do you still want the file to be _valid JSON_ or just an empty file? Specifically, opening any file in write mode will empty it; doesn't matter if its JSON

Comment: I don’t want the file to be deleted, just all the contents of the file.

Comment: I never said the file would be deleted.

Comment: json_dumps with an empty object. Same way you saved the results.